# How can I position an image to the side?

Tags: graphics

[image]

I want to position my text like this, to the side around the text but don't know how to. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\huge{\title{Introduktion}}
\author{Muhammad Ahmedov MTACI20h}
\date{Februari 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Jag är från Virserum (Jönköpings län) men bodde i Söderköping innan (ligger 20 minuter från Norrköping) så vi flyttade till vårt andra ställe här nere p.g.a. pandemin. Pluggade naturvetenskap på gymnasiet, tog studenten förra året och ansökte till fem läkarutbildningar efter studenten men kom inte in men civilingenjörsutbildningen i maskinteknik hos BTH var öppen för sen anmälan så tog min chans. Jag tycker verkligen om matematik, fysik, rita och konst rent allmänt, därmed att cada då man faktiskt skapar saker. På fritiden brukade jag vara mycket med vänner, gamea cod, spela schack och gymma men nu när studierna är så pass mycket hinner jag inte med det. Ursprungligen kommer jag från Uzbekistan, jag och familjen flyttade till Sverige för 15 år sen för att pappa och mamma tyckte att det fanns många möjligheter i Sverige men vi hade det väldigt bra i hemlandet annars, mamma arbetade som psykolog och pappa som civilingenjör han själv. Kan spanska och förstår ryska då mina föräldrar pratar flytande ryska 50 procent av tiden men kan själv inte prata flytande samt har jag en lillebror och en äldre syster.\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{image0.png}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\huge{\title{Introduktion}}` would make the whole document `\huge` (although in the preamble it does nothing) size commands like `\huge` do not take an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution, with the `\InsertBoxR` command from the plain TeX macro package `insbox`. It takes two mandatory  arguments: the number of unshortened lines before insertion in the following paragraph, and the object to be inserted, and one optional argument: the number of supplementary shortened lines, in case TeX does not make an exact calculation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

{\title{\huge Introduktion}}
\author{Muhammad Ahmedov MTACI20h}
\date{Februari 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\InsertBoxR{0}{\includegraphics[scale=0.7 ]{Nightmare_Fussli}}

\noindent Jag är från Virserum (Jönköpings län) men bodde i Söderköping innan (ligger 20 minuter från Norrköping) så vi flyttade till vårt andra ställe här nere p.g.a. pandemin. Pluggade naturvetenskap på gymnasiet, tog studenten förra året och ansökte till fem läkarutbildningar efter studenten men kom inte in men civilingenjörsutbildningen i maskinteknik hos BTH var öppen för sen anmälan så tog min chans. Jag tycker verkligen om matematik, fysik, rita och konst rent allmänt, därmed att cada då man faktiskt skapar saker. På fritiden brukade jag vara mycket med vänner, gamea cod, spela schack och gymma men nu när studierna är så pass mycket hinner jag inte med det. Ursprungligen kommer jag från Uzbekistan, jag och familjen flyttade till Sverige för 15 år sen för att pappa och mamma tyckte att det fanns många möjligheter i Sverige men vi hade det väldigt bra i hemlandet annars, mamma arbetade som psykolog och pappa som civilingenjör han själv. Kan spanska och förstår ryska då mina föräldrar pratar flytande ryska 50 procent av tiden men kan själv inte prata flytande samt har jag en lillebror och en äldre syster.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u sir, helped alot, love the image btw haha

Comment: F.y.i., it is   a painting from the Swiss romantic painter Johann-Heinrich Füssli, entitled ‘The Nightmare’

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the length of the text and the expected output, here are two different suggestions based on`wrapfig` or two side by side minipages:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.09]{image0.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
Jag är från Virserum (Jönköpings län) men bodde i Söderköping innan (ligger 20 minuter från Norrköping) så vi flyttade till vårt andra ställe här nere p.g.a. pandemin. Pluggade naturvetenskap på gymnasiet, tog studenten förra året och ansökte till fem läkarutbildningar efter studenten men kom inte in men civilingenjörsutbildningen i maskinteknik hos BTH var öppen för sen anmälan så tog min chans. Jag tycker verkligen om matematik, fysik, rita och konst rent allmänt, därmed att cada då man faktiskt skapar saker. På fritiden brukade jag vara mycket med vänner, gamea cod, spela schack och gymma men nu när studierna är så pass mycket hinner jag inte med det. Ursprungligen kommer jag från Uzbekistan, jag och familjen flyttade till Sverige för 15 år sen för att pappa och mamma tyckte att det fanns många möjligheter i Sverige men vi hade det väldigt bra i hemlandet annars, mamma arbetade som psykolog och pappa som civilingenjör han själv. Kan spanska och förstår ryska då mina föräldrar pratar flytande ryska 50 procent av tiden men kan själv inte prata flytande samt har jag en lillebror och en äldre syster.

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-5cm-10pt}
Jag är från Virserum (Jönköpings län) men bodde i Söderköping innan (ligger 20 minuter från Norrköping) så vi flyttade till vårt andra ställe här nere p.g.a. pandemin. Pluggade naturvetenskap på gymnasiet, tog studenten förra året och ansökte till fem läkarutbildningar efter studenten men kom inte in men civilingenjörsutbildningen i maskinteknik hos BTH var öppen för sen anmälan så tog min chans. Jag tycker verkligen om matematik, fysik, rita och konst rent allmänt, därmed att cada då man faktiskt skapar saker. På fritiden brukade jag vara mycket med vänner, gamea cod, spela schack och gymma men nu när studierna är så pass mycket hinner jag inte med det. Ursprungligen kommer jag från Uzbekistan, jag och familjen flyttade till Sverige för 15 år sen för att pappa och mamma tyckte att det fanns många möjligheter i Sverige men vi hade det väldigt bra i hemlandet annars, mamma arbetade som psykolog och pappa som civilingenjör han själv. Kan spanska och förstår ryska då mina föräldrar pratar flytande ryska 50 procent av tiden men kan själv inte prata flytande samt har jag en lillebror och en äldre syster.
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.09, valign=t]{image0.png}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank u so much.